# Mysql - Users Analysis with in a date range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've an activity tracker table with `activity_id` (Primary key, auto increment), user_id, api_function and date_added fields (please find the screenshot attached).

[image]

By using the below query I was able to count the number of entries per user in the last 28 days:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT date(date_Added) ) AS day_of_activity, user_id
       FROM activity_tracker
       WHERE date_added >= DATE( NOW() ) - INTERVAL 28 DAY
       GROUP BY user_id
       LIMIT 0 , 30
```

like:

```
days_of_activity    user_id
34  1
1   3
13  9
2  10
1  11
8  12
```

I need to track the count of users who have:

```
 more than 16 entries in the past 28 days
 between 6 to 16 in the past 28 days, 
 1 to 6 in the past 28 days, 
 no entries in the past 30 days, 
 no entries in the past 90 days and 
 no entries in the past 180 days.
```

Is it possible to do this in single mysql query?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No pictures, thanks. Just proper DDLs (and/or an SQLfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the answer below:

```
SELECT 

SUM(
CASE WHEN day_of_activity>16  AND last_activity_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 28 DAY  
THEN 1 ELSE 0
END)
as daily_users_count,

SUM(
CASE WHEN day_of_activity>6 AND  day_of_activity <=16 AND last_activity_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 28 DAY 
THEN 1 ELSE 0
END)
as weekly_users_count,

SUM(
CASE WHEN day_of_activity>=1 AND  day_of_activity <=6 AND last_activity_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 28 DAY 
THEN 1 ELSE 0
END)
as monthly_users_count,

SUM(
CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) >= last_activity_date OR last_activity_date IS NULL 
THEN 1 ELSE 0
END)
as not_in_30,

SUM(
CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) >= last_activity_date OR last_activity_date IS NULL 
THEN 1 ELSE 0
END)
as not_in_90,

SUM(
CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 180 DAY) >= last_activity_date OR last_activity_date IS NULL  
THEN 1 ELSE 0
END)
as not_in_180

FROM (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT date(at.date_added)) as day_of_activity, a.user_id, max(at.date_added) as last_activity_date
FROM accounts a 
LEFT JOIN activity_tracker at ON a.user_id = at.user_id
WHERE a.user_role_id = 2
GROUP BY a.user_id
)temp
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
    select CASE WHEN dates_of_activity>16 THEN count(*) ELSE
           CASE WHEN dates_of_activity>6 and dates_of_activity<17 THEN count(*) ELSE CASE WHEN dates_of_activity>0 and dates_of_activity<7 THEN count(*) ELSE count(*)
            END
            END END as count,
CASE WHEN dates_of_activity>16 THEN 'Above 16' ELSE
           CASE WHEN dates_of_activity>6 and dates_of_activity<17 THEN ' >6 and<16' ELSE CASE WHEN dates_of_activity>0 and dates_of_activity<7 THEN '>0 and <6' ELSE 'never use'
            END
            END END as typeday
 from (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT date( date_Added ) ) AS dates_of_activity
           , user_id 
    FROM activity_tracker 
    WHERE date_added >= DATE( NOW( ) ) - INTERVAL 28 DAY 
     GROUP BY user_id)a
     LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This query will fetch only the count of users with entries greater than 16. I'm in search of a solution with count of all types of users in a single query with something like mysql `case when`.

Comment: You can combine queries with `UNION`.